# window.location.href.replace does not replace the content of the url

Tags: javascript

I would like to redirect my current page to a page with similar URL except for one parameter.

Here is what I have tried

```
window.location = window.location.href.replace("trip-start="+/^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}$/g, "trip-start="+this.value);
```

and also:

```
window.location.search = window.location.search.replace("trip-start="+/^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}$/g, "trip-start="+this.value);
```

Unfortunately, the page is "redirected" (i.e refreshed) but the url stays exactly the same.

Am I missing something ?

Thanks you

**[EDIT]**

I investigated a bit, and actually the problem amount to this

```
let text = window.location.href;

let result = text.replace("trip-start="+/^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}$/g, "trip-start=2000-00-00");

alert(result);
```

the "result" is supposed to be the URL with the parameter "trip-start" set to 2000-00-00, but again, nothing changes.

Comment: that is not how regular expressions work. You can not add a string to a regular expression. `trip-start=` would have to be in the regular expression.

Comment: I want to replace a string that has the shape 'xxxx-xx-xx' (x are all intgerers) with another value of this form (this.value)

Comment: If you manually type the url into the browser(hit enter). What behavior do you have? does it stay on the manually typed url or go to the other one?

Comment: @ailauli69 your `replace` method is not working as you'd expect because you are mixing a string value with the Regex pattern which ends up being a string value that will not match anything and therefore your replace method will not work. Also, can you share the entire url string of the page that you are trying to change?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `history API`

```js
history.replace(newUrl)
```